# How to make hover state background 100% width on responsive images

Tags: jquery, css

I have created some responsive imagery but would like a hover state showing a usersname.

I have managed to create the hover state using Css and Jquery but unfortunately the hover background does not remain 100%  when I change the width of the screen.

Can anybody explain the best way to achieve 100% width background ? There is padding on my background image so I cant keep the black background flush to the image.

Here is a fiddle to explain what I mean.

I hope this makes sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/x59tB/15/

```
.show-username{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: inherit;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I updated your fiddle to include jQuery, but I'm not sure what you're asking for. It seems to work fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two issues:

The width style of this css rule is causing an issue with stretching. It will always override your existing style because id's have higher precedence than class selectors:

```
#upload-container ul li span {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 82%; // <---- Move this style
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 13px;
 }
```

Second add right and left declarations for your .show-username css rule:

```
.show-username{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: inherit;
    display: none;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```